# how to Apply custom excel format from html?

Tags: html, excel

I'm writing a code which its purpose is to export a html table to an excel sheet, but i have a problem with 1 column in the table where i have **time** with the following format: `0:12:12.185`. 
The problem is that this value is showed as Date in the excel sheet: `12:13:27 AM` but i want it to be displayed as it is in the html table: `0:12:12.185`.

After some research i found that i need to implement this custom format: `h:mm:ss.000` to get the result that i want, so i use it in the following css code: `mso-number-format:"h:mm:ss.000";` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve the problem by adding **non-breaking space**: `&nbsp;` before the value of the `<td>` element.
Example:
`<td>&nbsp;0:12:12.185</td>`

Instead of:
`<td>0:12:12.185</td>`